# useEffect with local variable

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to call useEffect funtion onchange of local variable, but its not working is only works if i use it with useState variable, I know there might be some basic thing here that I am not aware of.
sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-gareth-igyv7?file=/src/demo.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Demo() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  let valueOne, valueTwo;

  const setValueOne = (value) => {
    valueOne = value;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(valueOne);
  }, [value, valueOne]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <input
        placeholder="useState"
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="function"
        onChange={(e) => setValueOne(e.target.value)}
      />

      {/* {console.log(valueOne)} */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's because changing a local variable doesn't trigger a re-render and useEffect is not called. You would have to either use state or props.

Comment: What if the prop is also local variable of parent component?, If one tries to call function from parent  in child component's useEffect as props to give back data to parent with local variable?  Is there another way to have this without using useEffect.

Comment: changing `valueOne` won't cause a re-render, so `useEffect` won't execute if you change `valueOne`. What are you trying to do? Why not have `valueOne` in the state?

Comment: @Yousaf, I dont want to use useState as it causes re-render in complex project, In my application,  I am not able to type more than one character and it re-renders.

Comment: You can get around that by extracting `input` in a separate component and when `onChange` fires, it will only cause a re-render of that instance of the `Input` component that changed. You can't make `useEffect` execute on changing of a local variable like `valueOne`.

Comment: I have four level of hierarchy, where A imports B and that imports C, C imports D., here D has these input components, and i am trying to get value in the A, which is causing re render. Not sure what is better way to have this

Comment: I'm just curious to ask that why if we change value the second input, will it also change `valueOne`.

Comment: second input is calling setValueOne function which is assigning the value to valueOne

Comment: So after I change second input to `xyz` and then change first input, then it sshould console `xyz` right?

Comment: NO, first input is just example that i know how useState works, in second input I am trying to have same functionality without re render part. Both are separate

Answer (score 2):

setValueOne will not rerender your component, If you want to fire a re-render, useEffect function needs to have a useState which basically hold state between re-renders.

You can try managing your state like below, its more readable and it will work too.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Demo() {
  const [valueOne, setValueOne] = useState("");
  const [valueTwo, setValueTwo] = useState("");

  const handleValueOne = (e) => {
    setValueOne(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleValueTwo = (e) => {
    setValueTwo(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <input
        value={valueOne}
        placeholder="useState"
        onChange={handleValueOne}
      />
      <input
        value={valueTwo}
        placeholder="function"
        onChange={handleValueTwo}
      />

      {/* {console.log(valueOne)} */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I know how useState work, That is not the issue, Question is little different. To understand better, I have four level of hierarchy, where A imports B and that imports C, C imports D., here D has these input components, and i am trying to get value in the A, which is causing re render. Not sure what is better way to have this